# Laravel return response() not stop the execution

Tags: php, laravel

I can't find an explanation of why a `return response()` inside a `catch` is not stopping the execution, i guess im missing something.

In this example the request have an error so the try-catch on the service receive `ValidationException`. This goes to `ValidationErrorResponder` and here is where the execution should finish and return a json with the errors. But it continues and return the json error response through `$this->updateUserResponder->respond()`

I have a defined route which execute the `__invoke()` method on `UpdateUserAction`

```
class UpdateUserAction
{
    protected $updateUserService;

    protected $updateUserResponder;

    public function __construct(UpdateUserService $updateUserService, UpdateUserResponder $updateUserResponder)
    {
        $this->updateUserService = $updateUserService;
        $this->updateUserResponder = $updateUserResponder;
    }

    public function __invoke(Request $request, $userId)
    {
        $serviceData = [
            'id' => $userId,
            'commandPayload' => $request->only('name')
        ];

        return $this->updateUserResponder->respond($this->updateUserService->execute($serviceData));
    }
}
```

```
class UpdateUserService extends BaseService
{
    public function execute(array $data = [])
    {
        try {
            $this->bus->addHandler(UpdateUserCommand::class, UpdateUserHandler::class);
            return $this->bus->dispatch(UpdateUserCommand::class, $data, [UpdateUserValidator::class]);
        } catch (ValidationException $e) {
            return $this->validationErrorResponder->respond($e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
class UpdateUserValidator implements Middleware
{
    protected $rules = [
        'id' => 'uuid',
        'commandPayload.name' => 'max:256'
    ];

    protected $messages = [];

    public function execute($command, callable $next)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make((array) $command, $this->rules, $this->messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            throw new ValidationException($validator);
        }
        return $next($command);
    }
}
```

This shoudl return the final response wiht the errors in a JSON but

```
class ValidationErrorResponder
{
    public function respond($validator)
    {
        $messages = $validator->getValidator()->getMessageBag()->messages();

        return response()->json(['errors' => $messages], 422);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error it's another and the catch does not working because only are catching **ValidationException**.

So try catching all exception to see what happens:

```js
class UpdateUserService extends BaseService
{
    public function execute(array $data = [])
    {
        try {
            $this->bus->addHandler(UpdateUserCommand::class, UpdateUserHandler::class);
            return $this->bus->dispatch(UpdateUserCommand::class, $data, [UpdateUserValidator::class]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->validationErrorResponder->respond($e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `catch` is working fine because `$this->validationErrorResponder->respond($e);` is executed.